# +[UIView transitionFromView:toView:...] with multiple views

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, uiview

So here's the situation:

I have let's say 20 views who are all subviews of the same view. Now I want to remove and add new views in an animated matter. 
I previously did this by using regular UIView animations and fading them out or in respectively. The problem is though that the animation isn't flawless when the new subview who is to be inserted overlaps with the subviews who are fading out. So I tried using the `+[UIView transitionFromView:toView:...]` animation block to make the animation cross dissolve. This works well, animation looks good.
This basically solves my issue. The only problem is that it might be that I want to replace 2 subviews with one bigger subview. This doesn't really work out as I can't just pas `nil` to the transition method.

So my question basically is how I can simultaneously cross dissolve multiple subviews no matter how many views are animated?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the views to remove inside a transparent bigger view? So you just call transitionFromViewToView using the container with the 2 little ones inside and the big one that is entering?

Comment: I'm sure this would work but would be also quite complicated in my case. I think I'd still prefer the not-so-perfect animation over such a complicated solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`+ [UIView transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:), passing the common superview (usually `self.view` of your view controller) to perform all animations at once.

Excerpt from the doc:

> This method applies a transition to the specified view so that you can
>   make state changes to it. The block you specify in the animations
>   parameter contains whatever state changes you want to make. **You can
>   use this block to add, remove, show, or hide subviews of the specified
>   view.** If you want to incorporate other animatable changes, you must
>   include the UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent key in the
>   options parameter.

Comment: I'm aware of this method but if I think that's not quite what I'm looking for. This method animates the superview, so, unless I made a mistake, it animates every view, not only the ones I add/remove in the block.